# Qt Designer with Python: Connecting control dial with slider

Tags: python, qt

I am interested in making a seemingly simple RGB color controller that includes a control dial, 3 sliders for the different colors and 3 LCD numbers all in the Qt designer interface.

The dial points to places on a color wheel and I made the range of points around the dial to be from 0 to 360 so that Blue, Green, and Red maximums (red at maximum strength with blue and green outputting no color would give only red) occur at 0, 120, and 240 respectively.

The sliders take an input of an integer that the dial outputs.

I am wondering how I could make a slider start taking information at a point on the control dial and have the slider go up and down as it approached and retreated from that slider's maximum.

I was also wondering if there is a way to relate the control dial's output to the slider's input as a fraction (if the control dial point was 6, the slider's point would be 3).

Any thoughts on how this could be done or an easier way to go about the whole thing would be great!

Comment: have you read about signals and slots. Your sliders and dial both can emit the changed signals which you can catch and see the current value. based on that you can change you values (more slider up/down) and finally refresh the page.

Comment: I would like both to change at the same time and within certain number intervals of the dial. Is there a way I could code that? Or do I have to just operate them separately as you suggested? @Rash

Comment: have you read signals as I suggested. here is how it works. Changing any part of your GUI emits some signals that you can attach your code to. So if your dial changes, you can immediately catch that in code and there you can also change the slider. It happens very fast and it will give the impression that its all happening simultaneously. Let me find a simple example of signals for you.

Comment: This is a good example. http://www.pythoncentral.io/pyside-pyqt-tutorial-using-built-in-signals-and-slots/  Also if you are beginner I recommend you these video lessons.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=53oeJPKRttY&list=PLA955A8F9A95378CE

Comment: Yes I understand that you can simultaneously connect a dial to a slider with code like `QtCore.QObject.connect(self.controlDial, QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("valueChanged(int)")), self.horizontalSlider.setValue)` I am wondering if you could do something like ...self.horizontalSlider.setValue(int*(5/6))) or if it would be possible to set a value for the slider that isn't exactly the integer given as the output from the dial @Rash

Comment: yes that is possible. instead of using setValue, use a different method like mySetValue() that will take an int as a parameter. Then when the signal will pass the value to your function, you can manipulate it and then pass it to the actual setValue function

Comment: Thanks for all of your help @Rash. I have a good bearing on where I want to go, but am stuck on how to update a variable that changes with user input. So if I had ` QtCore.QObject.connect(self.controlDial, QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("valueChanged(int)")), self.some_method)` and wanted to create a method to edit every int that the controlDial puts out how could I do that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80090/discussion-between-fischer-and-rash).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This program has a dialer and a spin box in it. The dialer value is connected with a method which is passed the actual value of the dialer. Once the method receives this value, it goes ahead and does some operation in it (in this case halves it), and then passes the values to the spinbox value.

```
import PySide.QtCore as QtCore
import PySide.QtGui as QtGui
import sys

class MainWindow(QtGui.QDialog):
        def __init__(self):
                QtGui.QDialog.__init__(self)

                dial = QtGui.QDial()
                dial.setNotchesVisible(True)
                self.spinbox = QtGui.QSpinBox()

                layout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
                layout.addWidget(dial)
                layout.addWidget(self.spinbox)
                self.setLayout(layout)

                #connect this event to the given method. 
                dial.valueChanged.connect(self.changeSpinbox)

        def changeSpinbox(self, value):
                #do some operation on this value. In this case half it.
                self.spinbox.setValue(value / 2)

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
main_window = MainWindow()
main_window.show()
app.exec_()
```